# JS Build Error, Lint Error no-constant-condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, compiler-errors, eslint

Im getting error Unexpected constant condition no-constant-condition when trying to build this code. (Error is on line indicated with >>>)

The code runs off a user input, commandVariable0 & commandVariable1 take data from the input, in this case **b2b on** or **b2b off**, if they user should put **b2b test** then it should give the error warning: commandVariable1 is not a valid settings option.

Can anyone help me understand why this is not working, if a user puts **b2b test** it accepts it as valid.

Any help would be appriciated.

````
const b2b = function(data)
   {
      const commandVariable0 = data.cmd.params.split(" ")[0].toLowerCase();
      const commandVariable1 = data.cmd.params.split(" ")[1].toLowerCase();

  >>> if (commandVariable1 === "on"||"off")
      {
         b2bvar = commandVariable1;
         var output =
         "**```Bot 2 Bot Command Here```**\n" +
         `Embeded Messages : ${b2bvar}\n\n` +
         `Command Variable 0 : ${commandVariable0}\n` +
         `Command Variable 1 : ${commandVariable1}\n`;

         data.color = "info";
         data.text = output;
         return botSend(data);
      }

      data.color = "error";
      data.text =
         ":warning:  **`" + commandVariable1 +
         "`** is not a valid settings option.";
      return botSend(data);
   };
````

Please ignore the sloppy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your line
`if (commandVariable1 === "on"||"off")`
to
`if (commandVariable1 === "on" || commandVariable1 === "off")`

**What's the problem?**
In the above line JavaScript will first check if `commandVariable1` equals `"on"` and if not then it will convert `"off"` into a boolean and check if that's true.
Since the string `"off"` is a constant and will always result to `true` in JavaScript, your linter will complain about the unneccessary OR condition.